# Can someone explain 'virtual mass' in fluids in simple words (for a dummy/high schooler)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mass, terminology, flow, inertia

so I recently came across the term 'virtual mass' and when I looked up more about it, it just gave me some stuff about fluid mechanics that I dont understand properly. My understanding of virtual mass is that when a body is pushed through a fluid (let's say water) it moves slower than usual and behaves like hoe a big object with more mass would behave on land but then I realized that what I was thinking of is just upthrust/buoyancy so can somebody please explain virtual mass in simple (layman terms) words. (I just cant wrap my head around it)

Comment: Message for whoever voted for closing this question: if there is some Physics one ignores,it would be better to write a comment to ask for clarification before jumping to the "Close" link. Message for Infinite Void, a link to a relevant page describing the term and its context, would help your question survive.

Comment: Agreed. Because something isn't clear _to you_ does not necessarily mean it isn't clear to everyone else. The fault may lie with you.

Answer (score 0):

*Virtual mass*, or *added mass*, is a concept of fluidodynamics related to the enhanced inertia acquired by a body in a fluid. A short description of the concept can be found on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Added_mass).

It is an effect due to the coupling between a body in a fluid and the surrounding fluid. Indeed, the fluid's presence increases the body's effective mass because an external force, in addition to accelerating the body, has also to accelerate part of the fluid. Some simple examples can be found in the previously cited Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual mass, in the context of fluid mechanics, is a concept that can seem a bit counterintuitive but can be explained in simple terms.

Imagine you have an object moving through a fluid like water. When you push the object forward, it experiences a resistance from the water that slows it down. This resistance is due to the fact that the water around the moving object needs to accelerate and adjust its motion as the object passes through it.

Here's where virtual mass comes into play: It's as if the moving object temporarily "borrows" some of the surrounding water's mass. In other words, the object behaves as if it has more mass than it actually does when it's moving through the fluid. This additional effective mass is what we call virtual mass.

So, in simple terms, virtual mass is like an apparent or "virtual" increase in the mass of an object when it's moving through a fluid. This apparent increase in mass is a result of the object having to push against the fluid and cause it to move as well, which creates a resistance that makes the object feel heavier than it would in a vacuum or in a situation with no fluid.

It's important to note that virtual mass is more relevant at higher speeds or when the fluid's density is significant. In everyday situations, the effect of virtual mass is usually negligible, but in fluid dynamics and engineering, it can be a crucial factor to consider when designing systems involving the motion of objects through fluids.